# JsPDF: Error (Incomplete or corrupt png file)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to add a logo and I tried adding a picture but printing it will show this error:

```
Incomplete or corrupt PNG file
```

How do I solve this?

I recreated the problem here: https://codesandbox.io/s/js-pdf-with-data-printable-from-displayed-data-lup6ir?file=/src/App.js

```
  const handlePrint = () => {
    console.log("clicked");
    const doc = new jsPDF();

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "assets/logo-social.png";
    doc.addImage(img, "png", 10, 78, 12, 15);

    doc.text("Title here", 20, 10);
    doc.text("Sample", 20, 15);

    const columns = ["Data"];
    const rows = [];
    data.map((item) =>
      rows.push([
        item.cartItems.map(
          (item) => `${item.name}: ${item.color} = ${item.quantity}`
        )
      ])
    );
    doc.autoTable(columns, rows);
    doc.save("order.pdf");
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is not fully loaded at the moment of its usage in `doc.addImage`. Wait for the image to be fully loaded and call `addImage` then.

```js
const img = new Image();
img.src = 'image-url';
img.onload = () => {
  // await for the image to be fully loaded
  doc.addImage(img,'png',...);
  doc.text("Sample", 20, 15);
  //...
  doc.save('order.pdf');
};
```

Comment: I added it but there's still no picture https://codesandbox.io/s/js-pdf-with-data-printable-from-displayed-data-lup6ir?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The rest of the statements touching the `doc` must be also inside the callback. I've edited the answer to illustrate what I mean. If you don't put all the instructions making your pdf data inside the `onload` callback, adding text and saving pdf will occur before the image is gonna added. This is why you don't see the image.

Comment: is there something wrong with my codes? I added all of it in the `onload` but it won't print anymore https://codesandbox.io/s/js-pdf-with-data-printable-from-displayed-data-lup6ir?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think it's something with codesanbox way to load static files (images in your case). Try like this img.src = require("./assets/logo-social.png");